# How to delete some patterns in a shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell, sed

I need to add some code to this script to ignore some patterns stored in the PATHLIST. How can I remove these patterns to be ignored in the final report?.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATHLIST="/home/*/public_html/"

TMPFILE=/tmp/xs.tmp

echo > $TMPFILE

for i in $PATHLIST; do `find $i -mtime 0 -type f ! \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.gif" -o -iname "*.png" -o -iname "*.swf" -o -iname "*.psd" -o -iname "*.htaccess" -o -iname "*.pdf" -o -iname "*.FH11" -o -i$

if ! [ `cat $TMPFILE | grep [a-zA-Z] | wc -l` = 0 ]
then
   for i in `cat $TMPFILE`
        do
                echo "Found $i"

        done | mail -s "Recent changes detected" email@email.com
fi
```

Comment: question is not clear. can you be more specific

Comment: I cannot see the "done" of the for loop; the whole find command neither. Anyway... why is there a ` in the for loop body?

Comment: sorry, I edited question. I want simply to delete some patterns I choose for be ignored in the final report of this script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of serious errors in the code posted (i.e. echo nothing into a tmp file, open set of backticks, open for loop).

It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve, but it is evident that you are using both file globbing (i.e. the PATHLIST) and find to create a file list, when it would have been much better to simply use find.

You can ignore files with find via the -prune option.

```
find \( -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' -prune \) -o \( -print \)
```

Then just direct that output into a while loop to process each file.

If you can clarify what exactly you're trying to do, then I could make further suggestions...